# Error on creating local dataframe inside spark mapGroups function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm running the following code (spark version 3.0.1)

```
case class PubData(publisher_id:Int, country:String, platform:String)
case class PubRes(publisher_id:Int, status:String)

import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

val ds = obSpark.spark.table(tbl)
  .select("publisher_id", "country", "platform")
  .as[PubData]

val res = ds
  .groupByKey( pubData=> pubData.dwcl_publisher_id)
  .mapGroups{ case (pubId, pubDataIt) =>
        val localSpark = SparkSession.builder().appName("MyT").master("local")
                         .enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate() 
        import localSpark.sqlContext.implicits._
        val rdd = localSpark.sparkContext.parallelize(pubDataIt.toList)
        val localDF = rdd.toDF()
        // in real instead of take there will be ML based logic that need to be executed on localDF 
        localDF.take(10).foreach(println)
        PubRes(pubId, "OK")
 }
res.write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").save("/tmp/just_for_action")
```

This has the exception I'm getting in executor while running **take** and **print** and all the job fails.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.sparkContext(SparkPlan.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.readMetrics$lzycompute(limit.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.readMetrics(limit.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.metrics$lzycompute(limit.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.metrics(limit.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$.fromSparkPlan(SparkPlanInfo.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3616)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2697)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2904)
```

What is the reason, and how to make this work? I do need to create a local df inside mapGroups the real implementation should use SparkML logic there, and it should be local per group.

Comment: You can´t do that. Think that the anonymous function that you pass to mapGroups is executed for each row of the resulting KeyValueGrouped Dataset. There is no sense in creating a new context in each iteration. Besides, if you need to connect to two Spark clusters in the same application it´s not to be possible without the help of some external persistence (HDFS , database, Queue, etc ...). The second context has no idea of the memory(or disk) representations of the first cluster DFs or RDDs. Although the compiler said "It´s ok, go ahead"

Comment: That's exactly what I want, the spark context inside mapGroups to be matser=local, and not communicate with the cluster. I need that for using some spark based functions inside that method (think of it as simple POJO code, not distributed inside the mapGroup

Comment: The real life example - i need to create many logistic regression models. The mode will be per key. so I mapGroup and get the data per that key. I aware that in my case the data list inside the mapGroup is ok to load into memory. If I had python I would use scikit learn library for that. But in scala, I wanted to use sparkML lib, that why I needed the local session - to create a dataframe....

Answer (score 0):

You want to create two different Spark applications in the same scala program. Well, It is possible, but think that the first spark application creates a driver that handles the complete process pointing to a distributed cluster via a scheduler(Yarn, MEsos, K8s, standalone, ..). It generates a complete graph processing model that generates in memory data representations(distributed in the spark workers) that the another Spark app doesn´t know, so if you use the second context with data representations of the first one you obtain the nullpointer exception.

Because you need to create different models for each key I think the best option is to split the process in two steps. First, persist the resulting dataframe with a column that identifies the model to create and create another Spark app (master=localhost) that filter by this key and create the model for each set of data. Second, if you want to do in the same Scala program you have to collect the data to the driver, but the memory is limited and it will cause OutOfMemory errors because you need to serialize into Java objects representation, etc ... so you need to persist to a an external storage either way, unless your machine is big enough to support drivers with a lot of memory so you could use another libraries like http://haifengl.github.io/regression.html that work locally without any cluster. There are more possibilities, you could split the dataset in partitions and distribute Smile through the cluster to perform a LR model for each partition , thus having multiple LR models in parallel, etc, ..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I don't use any distributed related staff inside mapGroups. That's why I ran pubDataIt.toList to have a local list of data, and I succeed to create rdd and run take from it, but not from dataframe